# Processing Bullets interaction

Tags: animation, 2d, processing, collision, interaction

Hi How do I make bullets to collide with the objects in Processing ?
Bullets are fired and being translated and rotated 
but whenever i try to use function dist() it always gives me 0 as the position of the vector
How do i get the correct vector position if i want the bullet to collide with objects using distance and make the the other object disappear ?

Here's the code

```
void move(){ 
   passed  = passed + time;
   if (passed > bulletLife) {
      alive = false;
   }

   forward.x = sin(theta);
   forward.y = -cos(theta);
   float speed = 15.0f;
   velocity = PVector.mult(forward, speed);
   side.add(forward);

   void display(){ 
      pushMatrix();
      translate(side.x, side.y);
      rotate(theta);
      stroke(255);
      ellipse(side.x, side.y, 30, 30);
      popMatrix();
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you using the dist() function in this code? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Here's how i calculate distance  PVector kool2 = coordinates();
    float d = kool2.dist(location) / 10;

    
  }//end display()
  
    PVector coordinates()
  {
    PVector kool;
    kool = new PVector(side.x + cos(theta) * x2, side.y + sin(theta) * y2);
    return kool;
  }//end coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 0 from `dist()` because `translate()` moves the coordinate system! I think, more than your question, you need to reconsider your code overall. You translate to `side.x, side.y` (which will then be `0,0` until you call `popMatrix()`) but then you draw the ellipse at `side.x, side.y` which is offset from its actual position.

In other words: if the position is `100,200`, you're actually drawing the object at `200,400`!

If you skip the `translate()` part, you can use this to draw your object:

```
void display() {
  stroke(255);
  ellipse(side.x, side.y, 30,30);
}
```

And this to check collision:

```
if (dist(side.x, side.y, bullet.x, bullet.y) == 0) {
  collision = true;
}
else {
  collision = false;
}
```

You can also see my [collision-detection functions for Processing](https://github.com/jeffThompson/CollisionDetectionFunctionsForProcessing), which have lots of examples that might help.

Comment: Thanks for all of that, but when i skip the translate bullets just show up in random positions or at least not in the ship location

Comment: That's not what your questions is about, however. Maybe take this over to the Processing forum to get help?

You might also want to look into adding `PVectors`, such as using one for direction/speed.